# Can someone explain how i can use module.exports this way

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to understand what is going on when I use module.exports with a variable in a model view controller type project. I just do not understand what the book means by using it in this way

```
var express = require("./config/express.js");
var app = express();

app.listen(3000);
module.exports = app; // my problem is right here what is it doing 

console.log("Server running at http://localhost:3000/");
```

### my config/ express file is also here

```
var express = require("express");

module.exports = function()
{
  var app = express();


  require("../app/routes/index.server.routes.js")(app);
  return app;  
}
```

Comment: does this mean i can use module.exports = app; later in my app

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Please read [ask]

Comment: sorry that it did not seem like question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is exporting the Express app directly and the second example is exporting a *function* that *returns* the Express app.

This means that in the first example, `require(...)` will return `app`. In the second example, you would need to do `require(...)()` to have `app` returned.

Comment: so im exposing app in module.exports = app;

Comment: Yes, directly. Whatever you set to `module.exports` is what will be returned when calling `require()` on that module. By default, this is a plain (empty) object equal to the `exports` variable.

Comment: why expose app in module.exports = app

Comment: There is no real answer to that. It's mostly personal preference. You can export whatever you want however you want.